# Як правильно наукова *керівник* чи *керівниця* (ми говоримо про жінку)?

Tags: правопис

Написавши кілька речень до свого питання на сайті, я зазначила, що "..моя науковий керівник..." і коментар було відкореговано на "керівниця"...
Прошу допомогти зрозуміти, за яким правилом?

З [ukrlit.org](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/slovnyk_ukrainskoi_movy_v_11_tomakh/%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA):

> **КЕРІВНИ́К**, а́, ч. Той, хто керує ким-, чим-небудь, очолює когось, щось. Маса повинна мати право вибирати собі відповідальних керівників (Ленін, 27, 1951, 182); В одному містечку хлопця було відведено до керівника підпілля — столяра Якова (Ю. Янов., II, 1954, 11); — Керівник усе мусить знати і все передбачати (Шиян, Баланда, 1957, 147).
>
> ◊ **Кла́сний керівни́к** — учитель-вихователь класу в середній школі. Нещодавно його призначили до нас класним керівником (Сміл., Сашко, 1954, 221).
> Словник української мови: в 11 тт. / АН УРСР. Інститут мовознавства; за ред. І. К. Білодіда. — К.: Наукова думка, 1970—1980. — Т. 4. — С. 142.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Це, власне, просто жіночий рід до слова "керівник".

[Той самий словник](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/slovnyk_ukrainskoi_movy_v_11_tomakh/%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8F):

> КЕРІВНИ́ЦЯ, і, ж. Жін. до керівни́к.
>
> ∆ Кла́сна керівни́ця— учителька-вихователька класу в середній школі.
>   Їхня нова класна керівниця зайшла з практикантами-студентами (Ів.,
>   Таємниця, 1959, 92).

Comment: гадаю запитується про те чи треба обидва слова ставити в жіночому роді

Comment: @Yola якесь дивне запитання. Є два слова на позначення когось, хто керує, по одному для кожної статі. В сенсі, "чи треба?"?  Типу, чи треба казати "левиця", а чи може треба всіх львів називати "лев"? Я не розумію питання взагалі.

Comment: @P.Vovk на практиці не зустрічала, тому і запитую...
в деякій мірі питання дивне, але хотіла прояснити для себе
Дякую за коментарі!

Comment: @Orti я більше не розумів уточнення пана Yola, те, що не всі звертають увагу на деяку дивність називання жінок чоловічими іменниками, це нормально. Потрошку просто спадщину маємо побороти.

Comment: @P.Vovk це так само, як "директор" і "директорка".... Завжди говорили і писали - ".. директор школи...вона...."
На дверях табличка: "директор", але всі знають, що жінка...

Comment: @Orti щодо "завжди", думаю, ви перебільшуєте.

Comment: Я мав на увазі, чи можна сказати *моя наукова керівник*. Чи обов'язково обидва слова в жиночому роді ставити.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>*Не  на затверджену відповідь, такий собі [додаток](/a/3012/585) до відповіді пана [@Sasha](/users/4/sasha).*</sup>

[Українська фраза](//r2u.org.ua/node/192), 1928 • [Микола Сулима](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)

> #### § 4. Професійні назви
>
> Професійні й інші подібні до них назви в українській мові бувають здебільшого осібні для чоловіків і осібні для жінок. Українська мова взагалі уникає вживати в спільному роді тих слів, що означають посаду, професію, звання, рангу тощо, й надавати тим словам ознак граматичного (формального) чоловічого роду без огляду на стать. У російській мові, як відомо, такі слова, як от *автор*, *композитор*, *писатель*, а так само, напр., *товариш*, *приятель*, однаково можуть стосуватися до осіб жіночої статі, як і чоловічої.
>
> В українській фразі буває інакше: *він* – *автор*, *вона* – *авторка*; *він* – *композито*р, *вона* – *композиторка*; *він* – *письменник*, *вона* – *письменниця*; *він* – *лікар*, *вона* – *лікарка*¹; *він* – *професор*, *вона* – *професорка* й т. інш.
>
> Це так само, як, напр.: *танцюрист* і *танцюристка*, *учитель* і *вчителька*, *селянин* і *селянка*, *служник* і *служниця*, *робітник* і *робітниця*, *вʼязальник* і *вʼязальниця*, *полільник* і *полільниця*, *викладач* і *викладачка*, *асистент* і *асистентка*, *актор* і *акторка* (не „актьор, актьорка“; це – росіянізм) тощо.
>
> Подібно до цього російська фраза „она – мой приятель“ відповідатиме українській „вона – моя приятелька“. Так само, звертаючись до жінки (чи до дівчини) або говорячи про неї, по-вкраїнському вживають слова *товаришка* (а не *товариш*).
>
> Як бачимо з поданих прикладів, на професійні й інші аналогічні до них назви для жінок українська мова широко використовує відповідні формальні закінчення жіночого роду (граматичного), а втім це буває не завжди.
>
> Коли професійні жіночі назви можуть причинитися до плутанини, коли зміст фрази стосується не до самих жінок, а й до чоловіків, взагалі – до людей, то ми вживаємо чоловічих назов і для жінок. Наприклад: *Леся Українка – один із найкращих поетів*; коли б ми були сказали тут „одна з найкращих поеток“, то цим би ми підкреслили вагу Лесі Українки лише серед жінок-поеток, а не серед усіх поетів взагалі.
>
> Отже виходить, що професійні чоловічі назви, опріч свого спеціяльно-чоловічого значіння, мають ще й загальну силу, характеризуючи всіх людей якоїсь професії чи стану без огляду на натуральний рід, на стать. А жіночі назви мають завжди обмежене, специфічно-жіноче значіння. Згадаємо тут до речі оці слова: *людина*, *чоловік*, *жінка*. Слово *чоловік* у нашій літературній мові означає особу чоловічої статі, *жінка* – жіночої статі, *людина* обʼєднує в собі обидва ці значіння. Коли ми, маючи на увазі цю схему, кваліфікуватимемо значіння, напр., слів *поет* і *поетка*, то нам доведеться сконстатувати, що *поетка* йде рівнобіжно до *жінка*, а слово *поет* становить собою паралелю до *чоловік* і, опріч того, до *людина*. Отже значіння чоловічих назов – ширше, а жіночі назви – індивідуалізовані, обмежені на змісті.
>
> Через це, говорячи, припустім, про якусь жінку, що *вона – професорка історії*, іноді треба буває сказати, що *вона – видатний професор* (*знавець*) *історії*, вона – один із найкращих професорів (*знавців*) *історії*. З тих самих міркувань загального характеру ми кажемо про жінок іще й так, напр.: *вона – секретар Сільради*, *вона на посаді рахівника*, *діловода*, *статистика*, *лаборанта*, *асистента*; *вона – завідувач школи*² й інш.
>
> І ще одно завваження: звучи жінку чи дівчину *товаришкою* (а не *товаришем*), ми тимчасом можемо сказати так: *Серед усіх моїх товаришів вона – найкращий мій товариш*. Так само й це: *Вона – моя велика приятелька*, але *вона – найбільший приятель мені серед усіх моїх приятелів*. *Вона – революціонерка, але вона належить до найвидатніших революціонерів*. *Вона письменниця, але вона – найпопулярніший тогочасний письменник* і т. інш. Коли б і вдруге ми сказали були, напр., „письменниця“ (а раніше – „революціонерок“ тощо), то це не характеризувало б загальности, промовляло б лише за певне вузьке коло жінок, а не за всіх взагалі діячів якоїсь категорії.
>
> ---
>
> Виноски
>
> 1. Не можна лікарку звати *лікаршею*, *професорку* так само не можна звати *професоршою* й т. інш. *Лікарша* (*професорша*) – це лікарева (професорова) дружина. Опріч того, слова типу *лікарша*, *професорша* слід би вважати за вульгаризми (порівн.: наша *вчительша*; треба – наша *вчителька*), що виникли не без впливу рос. мови („генеральша, капитанша, офицерша“ й інш.).
> 2. До речі: замість *завідувач* не слід уживати невдалих новотворів „завідатель, завідуватель“; це зовсім непотрібні оцерковнословʼянені слова з напівмертвим наростком – *тель*.

Comment: Логічно. Але не покриває існуюче (на жаль) у сучасному світі прагнення до офіціозу. В результаті, НМД, «керівниця» має менший ступіть офіційності, ніж «керівник», а «наукова керівниця» — ще менший (бо «незвичне сполучення») — хоч так і не мало б бути. (Це жодним чином не Вам критика. І навіть не Миколи Сулими. Просто сучасні тенденції…)

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Відповідь дуже неповна. Хотів її видалити, але бачу, що вона вже отримала позитивну оцінку, тому не буду. Але зважайте, що вона враховує одні джерела/тенденції і **не враховує інші**.</sub>

## Чи можна використовувати чоловічу форму звання/посади/професії для жінки

**Так**. Принаймні, в деяких стилях мовлення. В **офіційно-діловому** стилі це навіть **заохочується/вимагається**.

Наприкад: *заслужений учитель Ольга Лозова*; *науковий керівник Наталя Богданівна*.

<sub>Про це бачимо зокрема у [навчально-методичному посібнику В. Л. Красюка «Ділова українська мова»](http://ftfsite.ru/wp-content/files/metod_ukr_3.1.pdf):</sub>

> <sub>Назви осіб за професією, посадою, званням, як правило, утворюють паралельні форми чоловічого й жіночого роду (учитель — учителька, працівник — працівниця).</sub>
>   <sub><…></sub>
>   <sub>Офіційними назвами посад, професій, звань є іменники чоловічого роду: директор, дипломат, професор; у діловій мові вони вживаються незалежно від статі особи.</sub>

## Як правильно узгоджувати чоловічу форму з іншими членами речення

#### В загальному випадку

**Прикметники** (і граматично подібні до них форми: присвійні займенники, порядкові числівники, дієприкметникові звороти тощо) йдуть у **чоловічому** роді. **Дієслова** (і граматично подібні до них слова/вислови) можуть іти у **жіночому**.

Наприклад: *наш старий менеджер звільнилася*.

<sub>Принаймні [так стверджує «Електронний підручник з сучасної української мови» Інституту філології Київського національного університету імені Тараса Шевченка](http://www.linguist.univ.kiev.ua/WINS/pidruchn/imen/vlad.htm#t4):</sub>

> <sub>Спільного значення роду набувають і вже раніше згадувані нами іменники типу *директор*, *економіст*, *декан*, *кандидат*, *доцент* та ін. Жіночий рід граматично виявляється в подібних іменниках досить своєрідно: прикметники узгоджуються з формою іменника, а дієслова (чи предикативні сполуки) — зі змістом цього іменника: *Наш викладач відповіла на наші запитання*.</sub>

#### В офіційно-діловому стилі

Офіційно-діловий стиль заохочує до навіть більшого використання чоловічого роду при узгодженні — дієслова (присудки) використовують жіночий рід **лише при зазначенні імені/прізвища** жінки.

Наприклад:
  • *головний технолог Оксана Леонідівна повідомила*;
  • *головний технолог повідомив*.

<sub>Про це каже зокрема той самий посібник Красюка «Ділова українська мова»:</sub>

> <sub>Текст набуває строго офіційного характеру, якщо слова, залежні від найменування посади, узгоджуються з цим найменуванням у формі чоловічого роду і в тих випадках, коли мова йде про жінок (*головний технолог повідомив*). Проте якщо в документі вказується прізвище жінки, яка займає вказану посаду, то підпорядковані слова узгоджуються з прізвищем і вживаються у формі жіночого роду (*головний технолог Сахновська В. І. повідомила*).</sub>

#### Різнотлумачення

Деякі джерела стверджують, що коли ім'я/прізвище не зазначено, то дієслова (присудки) мають узгоджуватися з граматичним родом іменника (а не семантичним) незалежно від використовуваного стилю. Мовляв, «наш директор запізнилася» не можна сказати навіть за межами офіційно-ділового стилю. По-моєму, це є перебільшенням.

[Оце джерело](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/59-rubric-89) стверджує, що в російській мові має значення ще й порядок слів — мовляв, дієслово, передує назві професії, не може бути в жіночому роді (наприклад, навіть за межами офіційно-ділового стилю варто казати «увлекательные заметки предложил редакции известный автор Наталия Петрова», а не «предожила… автор… Петрова») — але не впевнений, що це має якийсь стосунок до української мови.

## Висновки

Я не мовознавець, і роблю судження виключно на основі джерел, що прочитав, але здається так:

- «мій науковий керівник говорив» — можна (принаймні, в офіційно-діловому стилі);
- «мій науковий керівник говорила» — можна (принаймні, за межами офіціозу або якщо зазначено прізвище);
- «моя науковий керівник говорила» — здається, не можна («моя» неузгоджене з «керівник»);
- «моя керівниця говорила» — можна (принаймні, за межами офіціозу).

Тобто Вашу фразу «моя науковий керівник говорить» почали виправляти не дарма. Але от чи на стовідсотково правильний варіант її виправили — я стверджувати не можу, «мій науковий керівник говорить» було б однозначно правильно, але щодо «наукової керівниці» — з одного боку, слово «керівниця» в українській мові існує, є літературним і згідно зі словником означає саме керівника жіночої статі (на відміну від слова «секретарка», яке, хоч існує і є літературним, але не наслідує всієї множини значень слова «секретар», тому «вчений секретар» не еквівалентно «вченій секретарці»), а з іншого — стилістично може мати ще вужчу сферу вжитку, ніж перетин сфер «керівниця» і «науковий керівник», не кажучи вже про те, що словник може не враховувати всіх нюансів.